# Cross platform multi-language project generator?

Tags: projectgen

I'm looking for a project generator which can build project files for various IDEs like Visual Studio, XCode, SharpDevelop, CodeBlocks, etc and which supports both C/C++ and C# projects.

I've looked at CMake, but it seems like it lacks C# support.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

[Premake](http://IndustriousOne.Com/premake/) can generate project files for Visual Studio, MonoDevelop, SharpDevelop, XCode, Code::Blocks, CodeLite and plain GNU Make, and it supports building C#, C++ and C projects for  tons of platforms from Unix, Linux, OSX, Windows to crosscompiling for PlayStation 3 and XBox 360.

Comment: This looks like a really good solution at first glance.  Thanks!

Comment: So looked closer at Premake.  While its a step in the right direction it has a few thing that make it not ideal for us:

1. Its Lua based.... yet another language that is difficult to use because of lack of good debugging tools.  While i like Lua and have used it before and know there is a 3rdparty "ide" for it... i'd prefer to stick to C#.

2. Premake doesn't yet support VS2010 or XNA C# projects.  While we could extend it to support these we're getting into more development work which we wanted to avoid.

3. Premake's C# support is very simple and lacks project configuration settings.

Comment: @TomSpilman, it now supports VS2010.. still waiting it to support netbeans cnd or eclipse cdt

Answer (score 0):

You could use a template based code generation tools, eg CodeSmith, to generate files, but you would have to create the project templates yourself.

Comment: Some background info... we currently have a system developed in PHP using Smarty.  CodeSmith seems like Smarty with an IDE... which is nice, but i was hoping to find a solution that didn't involve us creating templates and managing their execution.

Answer (score 0):

syncProj:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1C1YrbFUVpTBXajbtrC62aXru2om6dy5rClyknBj5zHU/edit#
https://sourceforge.net/projects/syncproj/

If you're planning to use Visual studio for development, and currently only C++ is supported.